# Error 000445 in iterate Resample for rasters in Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, raster, iterator, resampling

I'm trying to resample rasters using a foor loop. Something is going wrong but i don't know what... This is my code:

```
import arcpy, os, math
from arcpy import env
from os.path import split, join
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = r"C:\resample da kernel\raster 11x11\input\morfom\cluster1"
outFolder = r"C:\resample da kernel\output_30"
rasterList = arcpy.ListDatasets("*","Raster")
for inRaster in rasterList:
    print inRaster # just to view progress
    outName = os.path.join(outFolder,str(inRaster))
    arcpy.Resample_management(inRaster, outName, "30",  "NEAREST")
```

the error i receive is:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000445: Extension is invalid for the output raster format.
Failed to execute (Resample).
```

any helps?

Comment: What if you `print rasterList`, what extensions do the rasters have?

Comment: Maybe related to this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210252/error-extension-is-invalid-for-the-output-raster-format-while-batch-projecting

Comment: What happens if you use `arcpy.ListRasters()` instead of `arcpy.ListDatasets()`?